# How to calculate percentage of change from a raster stack?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, raster

I have a raster stack (yearly time series) of land cover maps and I want to calculate the percentage of change. I have found [this question](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/How-to-calculate-decadal-average-and-percent-change-in-raster-stacks-td7589249.html), but is not clear to me. Any ideas how to do this?

Supposing that my raster stack is named `r_stk`, currently the only statistics that I have calculated are the `sd` and `cv`.

Any ideas on how to calculate the percentage change?

```
r_stk_sd<-calc(r_stk, fun=sd)
r_stk_cv<-r_stk_sd/r_stk_Mean
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some example data. From `?raster::stack`!

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

I understand you have done this

```
 mn <- mean(s)
 sd <- calc(s, sd)
 cv <- sd / mn
```

Now you want "% change" but you do not define it. Please edit your question, and explain better what you want to compute. Do you want local change (on a cell by cell bases); but if so, how would you compute the percentage? Or do you want it globally (one number for each layer / time period). Do you want to compare all time periods with each other? Or??

Here another possibility, compare the first layer to all other layers. Perhaps this can get you started to do what you want, or to ask a better question.

```
x <- s[[1]] != s[[-1]]
```

Are there any changed cells?

```
y <- any(x)
```

What is the total fraction of cells has changed relative to year 1?

```
cellStats(y, "mean")
#[1] 0.7923364
```

Or for each "year" relative to year 1.

```
cellStats(x, "mean")
#    green      blue 
#0.6218336 0.7891218
```

If you want year by year change, you could do

```
 s1 <- s[[2:nlayers(s)]]
 s2 <- s[[1:(nlayers(s)-1)]]
 z <- s1 != s2
 cellStats(z, "mean")
 #     green      blue 
 # 0.6218336 0.7672624
```